# python - UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 131198: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I tried to use the following code to decompress and read the dataset.........................................................................

```
# Import the dataset 
!wget https://research.aalto.fi/files/16859732/urlset.csv.zip

# import the necessary libraries

import zipfile
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import io

path_to_zip_file = "/content/urlset.csv.zip"
directory_to_extract_to= "/content/"

data_url = '/content/urlset.csv'

with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)

with io.open(data_url, 'r', encoding='windows-1252') as f:
    data = pd.read_csv(f)
```

However, I get the error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-4360b73cdc0d> in <module>
      1 with io.open(data_url, 'r', encoding='windows-1252') as f:
----> 2     data = pd.read_csv(f)

8 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py in read(self, nrows)
    222         try:
    223             if self.low_memory:
--> 224                 chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
    225                 # destructive to chunks
    226                 data = _concatenate_chunks(chunks)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 131198: character maps to <undefined>
```

What is the cause of the error?

Comment: Looks like the CSV file is broken in line 18233. Open it in a texteditor like mousepad, gedit or load it with libreoffice calc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the CSV file is broken in line 18232 and 18233. Open it in a texteditor like mousepad, gedit or load it with libreoffice calc.

Maybe you could ignore these 2 lines of your dataset? The code below will fix the file.

```
encodingError = 0
lineCounter = 0

with open('urlset.csv', 'r', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as inFile, open('output.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    while True:
        lineCounter += 1
        try:
            line = inFile.readline()
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            encodingError += 1
            print(f'encoding error in line {lineCounter}, error message: {e}')
            continue
        if not line:
            break
        outFile.write(line)

print(f'total skipped lines {encodingError}, due to encoding error.')
```

output of the code:

```plaintext
encoding error in line 18232, error message: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 122: invalid start byte
encoding error in line 18233, error message: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 2: invalid continuation byte
total skipped lines 2, due to encoding error.
```